# My disk usage is at 100%

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop

My disk usage is at 100% even when only one program (terra copy is running) which is reading / writing at 72 Mbps & system R/W speed is 11 Mbps. Is my HDD failing? It's almost 8 years old.
The details of the HDD are as follows: WDC WD10JPVT (Cap: 1TB)

[image]

Comment: A picture of Task Manager sorted by disk usage would probably be more useful.

Comment: 72MB/s (note the megaBYTE, not megaBIT) is a perfectly reasonable random read value for a 2.5" 5400rpm hard drive. Why would you expect it to do significantly more?

Comment: Is this happening only when you run TerraCopy or other times as well?

Comment: It's due to [IOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS) [**I**nput/output **O**perations **P**er **S**econd], as a mechanical HDD usually is only capable of ~10 IOPS, whereas SSDs are usually north of 30k.

Answer (score 1):

A disk usage of 100% does not necessarily mean that your hard drive is faulty. To check your drive for errors you can use software such as [hddscan.com](https://hddscan.com/) or use the built-in windows disk checker (instructions below). Since your hard drive disk is reasonably old, it might be a good idea to install your windows operating system on a ssd and use your current hard drive as a storage drive. This will speed up your operating system and probably solve this issue.

To check a drive:

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Click on 'This PC'
3. Right click on the drive you want to scan (in most cases C:)
4. Click on 'Properties'
5. Go to the 'Tools' tab
6. Under error-checking click 'Check now'.

Comment: I have already bought an ssd and also planning to upgrade the RAM. Thanks for your answer.